# how to find the sum of price for each day from 1st oct to till date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT count(*), sum(price) 
FROM Orders  
where creationDate > '2020-10-01' and creationDate < '2020-10-02'
```

this query gives total no of orders and the sum of price for 1st Oct.

I want the results for every day from Oct'1st to Till Date. On the particular day how many orders and the sum of their price.

Comment: use a `GROUP BY`  query

Comment: how  do I pass each day(from Oct1st) to till today to this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by`:

```
select convert(date, creationDate) creationDay, count(*) cnt, sum(price) total_price
from Orders  
where creationDate >= '20201001' and creationDate < dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, getdate()))
group by convert(date, creationDate)
order by creationDay
```

If you want a *running* count and sum, then use window functions:

```
select convert(date, creationDate) creationDay, 
    sum(count(*)) over(order by convert(date, creationDate)) running_cnt, 
    sum(sum(price)) over(order by convert(date, creationDate)) total_running_price
from Orders  
where creationDate >= '20201001' and creationDate < dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, getdate()))
group by convert(date, creationDate)
order by creationDay
```